# cell background color is not visible while selecting particular row on ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-validation

I am currently working on agGrid

Unable to see cell background color when i select particular row in ag-grid

(Here row color overrides).

check below screen shot for reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATE0h.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sbJq.jpg)

AgGrid version 27.2.1

It's very helpful for me if you guys find the solution

Thanks in advance

Here cell color should be visible when we select row

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image you provided, it looks like you need [cellClass](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-styles/#reference-styling-cellClass) to add a class name to cells in a specific column. Then, you can manipulate the background color of that class using a [custom stylesheet](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/global-style-customisation/) file.

##### Example:

`javascript`

```js
// Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/1NeMKcO0m2bqjI19?open=index.jsx&preview

import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css'; // if using alpine theme
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import './styles.css';

... 
// Provides cell class

const columnDefs = [
    // return same class for each row
    {
        headerName: 'Static Class',
        field: 'static',
        cellClass: 'my-class'
    },
    // return same array of classes for each row
    {
        headerName: 'Static Array of Classes',
        field: 'staticArray',
        cellClass: ['my-class','my-class1'],
    },
];

<AgGridReact columnDefs={columnDefs}></AgGridReact>
```

`css`

```css
.ag-theme-alpine {
  --ag-selected-row-background-color: green;
}

.my-class {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Hi In plunker it works as expected but in my project still appearing cell Color even though  if i use cellClass property

Comment: @Teja Please add your code. I will looker over it.